# Como darle formato de URL a una variable que es enviada por la URL en PHP

Tags: url, enlace

Resulta que estoy enviado una variable por la URL llamada *$errors* que es donde están todos los errores que ha cometido el usuario y la estoy mandado por la URL para recibirla en otra pagina. La variable me llegan muy bien sin ningún problema, pero resulta que me esta llegando de una manera muy fea que no es agradable para el usuario, entonces me gustaría saber si en **PHP** existe alguna función que me ayude a convertir mi variable *$errors* a convertirla a una URL mas bonita y amigable a los ojos del usuario, algo como esto: *localhost:proyecto/error-en-tu-peticion*

**Esta es la manera que en me queda mi URL**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo fea ¿no?

Amigos espero que me puedan ayudar y espero que tengan un excelente día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de enviarla puedes reemplazar los espacios (que en la url se muestran como %20) por un guión con `str_replace`.

```
$error = str_replace(" ","-",$error);
```

Y si la vas a usar como texto en la página de destino, puedes volver a reemplazar guiones por espacios con la misma función.